Ignoring Entity Framework Migration files in EditorConfig
I have an EditorConfig file with the following content
root = true

# Generated Code
[{*.Generated.*.cs,*/Migrations/**,*/Scripts/**}]
generated_code = true


# C# files
[*.cs]


# Indentation and spacing
indent_size = 4
indent_style = space
tab_width = 4

# New line preferences
end_of_line = crlf
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = false

etc. (another ~500 lines of rules)

My project structure looks like this, with the .editorconfig in the project root.

However, I am still getting compiler warnings for files under the Migrations folder which should be ignored if they are marked as generated code.

I'm not sure what is wrong with my EditorConfig.
I have tried several different variations and none of them seem to work. I have tried all the following:
Only check files: (single asterisk)
[{*.Generated.*.cs,Migrations/*,Scripts/*}]
generated_code = true

Separated into multiple statements:
[*.Generated.*.cs]
generated_code = true

[*/Migrations/**]
generated_code = true

[*/Scripts/**]

generated_code = true

Separated into separate statements at the root:
[*.Generated.*.cs]
generated_code = true

[Migrations/*]
generated_code = true

[Scripts/*]
generated_code = true

What is the correct syntax needed to accomplish this?
Thanks

Could you kindly provide the following information: 1. Is ‘xxxxxx.xml‘ included in your project file? 2. Can you provide your way to create editconfig file and steps to help us reproduce your problem? 3. Does the snippet below work: # C# files [*.cs] dotnet_diagnostic.CS1591.severity = none

@MinxinYu-MSFT

Yes I have a  tag in the project file.
2a. The first code snippet I provided should be sufficient for reproducing.
2b. I am using Add-Migration Init.Generated -p MyProject -s MyOtherProject -o Migrations -Args '--environment Test' to create a migration in the Migrations folder.
I do not want to set the severity to none - I want this warning for non-generated files.


Did you ever solve this?

@MikeNakis not exactly. I had to create another .editor config and place it in the Migrations folder
Suppress warnings on auto-generated migrations.
root = true
All files
[*]
generated_code = true
dotnet_diagnostic.CS1591.severity = none
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = none

Did you try the pattern [*_Init.cs] ?

I don't think so? Can you elaborate?

Just a quick reminder - when you added the  tag to the project file, the DocumentationFile option applies to all files in the project. If you don't want to ignore the CS1591 warning globally, we recommend that you either add an XML comment in the corresponding location mentioned in the warning (you can refer to this link for more information) or add a comment in the corresponding file using #pragma warning disable CS1591 and add #pragma warning restore warning-list where you want to restore warnings received (again, you can refer to this link for more details).
